# Halting progress of an HTML POST with a PopUp box if the fields are not filled out

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm creating a webpage which has several fields. I do not want the php code to execute unless all the fields are filled out as that will create an error.

Here is my html code:

```
 <html>
 <body bgcolor="AliceBlue">


<form action="WorkingVersionV2.php" method="post">
<p>Which database do you wish to access? <center> <input type="text" name="database"/>     </center></p>
<p>What table would you like to examine? <center><input type="text" name="oldtablename"/></center></p>
<p>What would you like to name the table produced? <center><input type="text" name="newtablename"/></center></p>
<p>Start at row: <center><input type="text" name="startrow"/></center></p>
<p>Number of rows to search through:<center> <input type="text" name="numberrows"/>     </center></p>
<center><input type = "submit" onclick="checkFields()"/></center>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkFields()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("database").innerHTML;
    if(x=="")
   {
        alert("You forgot to enter a database name");
       }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I figured throwing a pop up box would halt the user if the fields were not filled out. However, when the user clicks submit, the pop up box is not thrown up, and I'm unsure whether the php code will still execute once they close it.

HTML/javascript is not my forte, if you have a better or easier way of doing this then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the input type=submit for non-javascript browsers then you need to make a few changes.

You javascript function needs to return a value like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkFields()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("database").innerHTML;
    if(x=="")
    {
        alert("You forgot to enter a database name");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

And you should change your input button like so:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return checkFields();" />
```

Comment: This method will still submit the data if the user has javascript disabled. It is always a good idea to expect incorrect input on the server side of the script and return a user friendly error if this happens. Even if your javascript is perfect, someone could still write a script to send bad information. Never completely rely on client-side error checking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want javascript to STOP an event from continuing once leaving your event handler (such as a form submit, or a link click), then simply return false from your event handler.

```
function checkFields() {
    var x = document.getElementById("database").innerHTML;
    if(x=="") {
        alert("You forgot to enter a database name");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, you must attach the event handler to your form in order for it to be called once it is submitted:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return checkFields()" ...
```

However, this method of attaching event handlers in JavaScript has fallen out of favor.  Although it will work, there are [better methods](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When you submit the form you're going to want to tell it that it needs to run the function, in this case the validation function. This is done with the onsubmit="function()" 
Return false wills top the execution of the script.

Comment: I'd love to see an explanation instead of just a code-only answer... I'll give +1 if I see an edit :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkFields()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("database").innerHTML;
    if(x=="")
    {
        alert("You forgot to enter database name");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

The input button part is the most important. Be sure to return the function

```
 <input type="submit" onclick="return checkFields();" />
```